# Is there a way to find out which changesets I haven't synced to?

Tags: tfs

In TFS I can do:

```
> tf get /preview
```

to find out which files have changed since I last synced. But I want to know which changesets those file changes belong to.  Something like the output of 'tf history' applied to the changes I'm missing.

Is there a built-in way to do this?

(Note: I'm a command-line person, so an answer that uses the IDE is of less value to me.)

Answer (score 4):

I think `tf history . /r /v:W~T` will give you what you are after for the current directory and below.

That says to run history from your workspace version (`W`) to tip (`T`).

Answer (score 1):

Using the PowerShell snapin from the PowerToys:

```
Update-TfsWorkspace -Whatif
```

will list outstanding changes.