# How to check if there are new changsets on TFS server?

Tags: tfs, mercurial, tortoisehg

I was a user of [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) for very long time and got very used to a `hg incoming` command. It shows what is the difference between my local [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/) repository and remote server.

I was using it daily to check what others committed and together with [`tortoisehg`](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/)  I was able to quickly review commits of others.

Is there a similar command available in `TFS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest behavior to

```
hg incoming
```

is

```
tf history . /recursive /format:detailed /version:W~T
```

It shows a windowed (`/format:detailed`) list of changes from workspace version (`W`) until tip (`T`) on the server.

Answer (score 1):

One way of accomplishing this would be to find the latest changeset number in your local workspace first and then right click the branch to find it's history and associated changesets. If the local changeset and the last changeset in view history is same then you dont have anything to review or else you have changes to review.

To get the changeset number from your local workspace you can use the following command, as per this [MSDN Buck Hodges](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2009/01/26/how-to-determine-the-latest-changeset-in-your-workspace.aspx): This should be run from the root of your workspace in the commandline.

```
tf history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W
```

*You are also trying to follow the same process that you have been doing all along, have you tried exploring some of the code review functionality which TFS2012 gives? Check that out as well [HERE](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/get-code-reviewed-vs.aspx).*

Hope it helps!

Comment: No VS Premium in my hack town unfortunately... But page you mentioned gave me some hints.

Answer (score 0):

From a command line in your source folder use

```
tf get /preview
```

It will show what would occur if you did a get latest, effectively telling you what changes are incoming.

If you want the change set details as well, have a look at the answer to:  [Is there a way to find out which changesets I haven't synced to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217083/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-which-changesets-i-havent-synced-to)

Comment: tf get /preview is close but not enough: it shows files changes collapsed and they are not grouped by changeset.